# When no relation found, return a fallback Active Record relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model `Camping` with many `Image`s.

```
class Camping < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
end
```

And I want it to always return an image, even if none is given, a fallback_image. I thought to fix this with overloading the attribute-getter:

```
class Camping < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images

  def images
    attributes["images"] || [Image.new]
  end
end
```

This works, but not transparantly. For example, a controller calling `limit()` or another active-record method will now fail, if the fallback is used:

```
Camping.find(1).images.limit(4)
#=> undefined method `limit' for #<Array:0xb0b85eec>
```

How can I ensure such a fallback more transparantly? Did I miss some utility in ActiveRecord that provides such functionality already, without having to overload?

Comment: Is there a reason that you're not associating this default image during the creation of the Camping object?

Comment: Why not have that check in your controller?

Comment: Have you tried `self.images || Image.new` ?

Comment: @Max: I might misunderstand you, but `self.images || Image.new` will return either *a list* of images or *one* image, which is even further from what I have now. Currently it at least "quacks like an enum".

Comment: @jdl: Not particularly, but note that I am not interested in storing this relation, so I'd need quite some logic to avoid having that fallback-image when any of the `images<<`, `images=` or other active-record-helpers are used to assign images somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, I left off the braces in my previous comment. I'm not sure there'

Comment: you could `self.build_images` if they are not present, but either what you're doing is super smart or super stupid.

Comment: I tried self.build_images and even tried that in an `after_find` callback. Problem is that in that the Image.new gets added and gets saved. I don't want that: I want it to only return a _quacks as an AREL relation List of one images_ when there are no Images associated.

Comment: I assume you want to implement something like [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) for your Images relation. I don't think that this is a clever thing to do for a relational dependency in rails. Could you show the exact usecase what you actually use this for?

Comment: Did you try `build` with `autosave: false` on the association?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with that, phoet? Should I `build`  in the `def images`?